# How to describe buying a drink with a cheaper price when buying a meal set

Tags: meaning-in-context

I'm a HongKonger and my mother language is Cantonese (A kind of Chinese?).
I just wonder the sentence that I read on the restaurant menu is correct.
"Upon Purchase Of Above Set, Can Enjoy Premium To Purchase Set Drink"
It is quite hard for me to understand the meaning of the above mentioned sentence if I did not read its Chinese version. Is it the right way to present its true meaning?
I'd like to translate it as below:
"Enjoy favorable price for set drink on purchasing any of above meal sets."
Can you understand form my translation?
Or is there any better way to present?

Comment: Will the work for things that are not drinks, like fries or any other side-order?

Comment: LunisHong, you may not be aware that our other site [ell.se] is the best place to look for answers on English questions that a fluent speaker would find trivial. If you have a question for ELL, be sure to read their guidance on [what you can ask](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). :-)

Answer (score 3):

While your translation does not make use of words commonly used in advertising, the meaning is understood.

In the US, we refer to this as a "meal deal". It would be presented something like this:

***MEAL DEAL: Get a large drink for the price of a small, with purchase of meal.***

Comment: The version on the menu is not idiomatic English. We would say something like '20% off drink when bought with meal'.The expression 'meal deal; is used in Britain too, usually expressed in the form 'Sandwiches + crisps + drink for [price]'.

Comment: 'Meal-deal' sounds right to me, but note that it was probably coined by one fast-food company (I don't know which one)

Comment: @Mitch I don't know if it was coined / first-used by any particular fast-food company, but at least in the UK -- as Kate says -- it is commonly found in almost any chain of shops (and possibly independent ones) catering (primarily) to the lunchtime sandwich market. That all the ones I've seen tend to use the same term – "_Meal Deal_" – suggests that if one company _did_ coin it first, they never trademarked it to prevent others from using it.

Answer (score 2):

We don't usually call the lower price for the drink a "premium". The more common word is "[discount](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/discount?r=75&src=ref&ch=dic)". So it might be written as

> Get a discount on a large soda when purchased with one of the above meals.